# AWS adding ssl certs to load balancer

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

We have the ssl certs from symantec and have added them to the LB in aws which is currently holding one ec2 instance. We are also using route53 for dns. https://domain.com isn't working, port 80 is ok. I've verified my security groups are allowing 443 for ec2 and lb.
I've been using www.wormly.com to test SSL and notice that the domain.com fails but the FQDN of the load balancer passes "green" for the certs but not the domain.com...
Does the csr need to use the FQDN of the aws load balancer?

Comment: No, you don't need the ELB's FQDN in the CSR (and you can't add it) so it isn't that.   Please explain more clearly what "isn't working" means.  Certificate warning? Browser error? (Connection times out? Connection refused? Something else?)

Comment: this error will appear in chrome for example:
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.mydomain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: When you added the cert to the ELB did you include the intermediate/root certificate bundle?

Comment: Yes, intermediate and root were included.

Comment: Has the ELB been configured with an HTTPS listener that's associated with that certificate?

Answer (score 0):

There were residual dns records that had to be updated on godaddy unbeknownst to me due to my not having initially purchased the domain.